# Could not find :projA:. Required by: project :app

Tags: java, android, android-studio, development-environment

I'm trying to run my app but this error appears in my terminal. I had some problems with SDK before and I was changing build.gradle file.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion rootProject.findProperty("android.compileSdkVersion") as Integer
    defaultConfig {
        targetSdkVersion findProperty("android.targetSdkVersion") as Integer
        minSdkVersion findProperty("android.minSdkVersion") as Integer
        applicationId findProperty("android.applicationId")
        versionCode findProperty("android.minSdkVersion") as Integer
        versionName findProperty("android.versionName")


        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

        buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    }}

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:30.0.0'
    implementation(name:'projA', ext:'aar')
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
}
```

If you have some advices, what I can do, please help me with it.

Comment: `implementation(name:'projA', ext:'aar')` where is this dependency supposed to be resolved from?

Comment: from build.gradle file

Comment: No, there needs to be a file `projA.aar` somewhere in a (to be configured) repository to make this work. This is probably the output of another project's build?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem with code is this line

```
    implementation(name:'projA', ext:'aar')
```

Now this asks gradle to find for a library that has aar extension . Generally it is located in the libs folder located at `your_project_folder/app/libs/projA.aar` . If you are sure you need this dependency called `projA` place it in the directory mentioned above . Or remove that line if you do not need it and gradle sync it.

Comment: I've already resolved it by reinstalling packages, but anyway thank you for answering.